# cocos2d v3 CCActionCallFunc with object?

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone

In cocos2d previously I had used CCCallFuncN and CCCallFuncND

I am attempting to call a function and send the object through to the function. I've tried a couple implementations which don't seem to be working.  My latest attempt with CCActionCallBlock looks like this:

```
[gun runAction:[CCActionRepeatForever actionWithAction:[CCActionCallBlock actionWithBlock:^
{
    CGPoint gunPoint = CGPointMake(gun.position.x - gun.contentSize.width/2, gun.position.y);

    CGPoint shootVector = ccpSub(gunPoint, _playerPos);
    float gunAngle = -1 * ccpToAngle(shootVector);
    gun.rotation = CC_RADIANS_TO_DEGREES(gunAngle);
}]]];
```

And I am receiving the following error:

> -[CCActionCallBlock elapsed]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x15f84c50
>   2014-03-02 16:54:19.768 JuhnerickShooterFinal[22576:70b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[CCActionCallBlock elapsed]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x15f84c50'

Can someone shed some light on how to pass the object into the Called function from the Action.

Thanks :)

Comment: remove the repeat forever action, instead schedule an update selector in the target node if you need to run code every frame. you can use the block action to issue the scheduling.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you can see from the [CCActionCallBlock reference](http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/api-ref/3.0-rc1/Classes/CCActionCallBlock.html), it's an *instant action* which doesn't contain the `elapsed` method, which is within the `CCActionInterval` class (and all subclasses).

If you want something to happen every frame then simply add the code to the node's `update` method:

Gun.m:

```
- (void)update:(ccTime)delay {
    GPoint gunPoint = CGPointMake(self.position.x - self.contentSize.width/2, self.position.y);
    CGPoint shootVector = ccpSub(gunPoint, _playerPos);
    float gunAngle = -1 * ccpToAngle(shootVector);
    self.rotation = CC_RADIANS_TO_DEGREES(gunAngle);
}
```

Note: you will need to figure out how to access `_playerPos` in the code above.  `Player` could be accessed via a singleton-like pattern from the game scene.

Comment: Thanks- looks like I need to restructure a bit of my program to make this possible- am currently updating my older project from cocos2d 0.99 to cocos2d v3 :)